# Python request illegal instruction

Tags: python

I'm trying the following code:

```
def checkBarCode(barCode):
    r = requests.get('https://google.com')
    print(r.status_code)

checkBarCode('test')
```

But it returns: Illegal instruction (SIGILL)
It's the same no mater if I use POST or GET.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm running om Raspberry Pi 3b+ and Raspberian OS

Comment: Either your Python environment, requests module or something that requests depends on is corrupt.

Comment: Delete and re-install python, delete and re-install requests, restart your PC

Comment: Almost certainly a problem with your python install.  Something at the *assembly level* is calling an opcode your cpu doesn't support.  It's possible that's in requests (does it have C code?) but much more likely python.  And your comment below suggests as much.  Did you install python in some nonstandard way?  Have you got the right rasberian for your rpi?  In any case this has nothing to do with your python code, which is fine (albeit it doesn't check barcodes).

Comment: This can happen if e.g. you have an i586 cpu but software compiled for i686. In the case of the rpi however I'm wondering if you've actually got something horrible, like x86-64 binaries trying to run on an arm?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the Python code, so I must assume your installation for `requests` is broken. Have you tried reinstalling the dependency? e.g. on Linux using Python3:

```
python3 -m pip install --force-reinstall requests
```

Comment: I get this response:
python3 -m pip install --force-reinstall requests:

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Illegal instruction (SIGILL)

Comment: So your Python interpreter is broken, you'd have to reinstall it. How to do it would depend on the distro you're using. On Ubuntu, f.e.: `sudo apt install --reinstall python3`. On Windows or OS X you'd have to run the installer again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran these commands, and they solved it:

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade